# get dynamically the x & y values of a raphaeljs element even if it moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

how to get dynamically the x & y values of a raphael js element even after a zoom or a left or right move, I want to show a div near to my element, when I show the element.getBBox() values I found that they don't change even if I move the element or I zoom in/out, my code that I use to get x & y values seems like this :

```
x = (myElement.getBBox().x+myElement.getBBox().x2)/2;
x+=$("#container").offset().left;
y = (myElement.getBBox().y+myElement.getBBox().y2)/2;
y+=$("#container").offset().left;
```

and the code that moves my div (a tooltip) is :

```
$("#myTooltip").css({"left":x+"px","top":y+"px"}).show();
```

Note : it works when I do the same thing with mouse coordinates (using `x=e.pageX;y=e.pageY;`) but in this case I want to do it when I click on another button in the page

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using Raphael and came across to what I think you need in your project.
In order to understand how `x` and `y` can be shown dynamically, look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/qd6e4/)**:

While you are dragging objects around, you can see their coordinates change dynamically. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `myElement.attr('x')` and `myElement.attr('y')` instead of `myElement.getBBox().x` and `myElement.getBBox().y`, thank you A.S. Roma, don't forget to say hello to Totti

**Edit :**
if someone have the same problem, the best solution I found untill now is to use jquery and raphael, explication :
First of all I need in the definition of the element to add an ID like this : `myElement.node.id='myUniqueId'` and after that you can access to the element using jquery like this `x = $("#myUniqueId").offset().left` and `y = $("#myUniqueId").offset().top`